# Creating a Java date from YMD HMS values without using deprecated code

Tags: java, date, deprecated, utc

I'm spending some time with Java again after a long break on the .NET side.  I came across this code:

```
Date date = new Date(Date.UTC(y - 1900, m - 1, d, h, M, s));
```

Unfortunately `Date.UTC` has been deprecated for a while.  So, what is an equivalent replacement that won't cause compiler warnings?

Comment: The Date constructor you are using is also deprecated, not just the Date.UTC.

Comment: @Strawberry, really?  It's not in JDK 1.6. To be clear, it's `Date(long)`.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date(long)

Comment: Whoops sorry I thought it was the java.util.Date and in fact java.util.Date(long) isn't actually deprecated... Two mistakes for the price of one :)

Comment: @Strawberry, actually it is a java.util.Date, I just pasted the wrong link.  But it's not deprecated either: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(long)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.set(year, month, day,
        hour, minute, second);
Date date = cal.getTime();
```

You GregorianCalendar also supports setting the TimeZone if needed.

Comment: I ran this in a unit test and it doesn't give the same `Date` as the one in the question.

Comment: The Date (getTime() in milliseconds) is not as the same as above? Or the actual Date (Month/Day/Year HH:MM:SS)? Make sure that the TimeZone is set correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Calendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)
 Specifically use [`set()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method, Also there is very good API [joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

**Update**

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
cal.set(y, m, d, h, M, s);
Date date = cal.getTime();
```

Comment: Yeah use Calendar.getInstance() with TimeZone of UTC then build use the set method as above.

Comment: I am making a library for others to consume so I don't want to force a dependency on them.  `set` returns `void`, so what do I do after that?

Comment: It will set the specified time into calendar object, if you want to retrieve `Date` then invoke `getTime()` on calendar instance

Comment: What a weird API.  I can see why people like joda so much :)

Comment: Do I need to subtract 1900 still?  I'll accept any answer that shows equivalent code in full, like I asked in the question.

Comment: @Drew Why weird :) ? It seems you are trying to write same API :)

Comment: Well "To get the Date, call getTime" is a little counter-intuitive for a start.  Also, what is the magic string that gives you a UTC calendar?

Comment: I ran this in a unit test and it doesn't give the same `Date` as the one in the question.

Comment: It will give the date representation on your system's timezone

Answer (score 1):

Use [Joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).  It's just awesome and a huge leap from the standard Java Date/Time libraries:

```
new DateTime(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth, hourOfDay, 
             minuteOfHour, secondOfMinute, millisOfSecond, 
             DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

But if you don't like having all those params which are easily confused you can also use take builder-style approach:

```
new DateTime()
    .withYear(2011)
    .withMonthOfYear(6)
    .withDayOfMonth(12)
    // etc...
    .withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

Each call to withXxxx() returns a copy so DateTime remains immutable.

Comment: Cheers, but I'm producing a library for others to consume and don't want to introduce a new dependency.

Comment: @Drew: fair enough - but you could use Maven assembly to bundle everything together into your library for distribution.